# Ubuntu 14.04 flickering screen on high resolution

Tags: 14.04, resolution, intel-graphics, flicker

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 7000 7548 with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot. It has a built-in 4k display with Intel HD Graphics 5500(Broadwell GT2) graphics. Everything runs as normal on Windows, but on Ubuntu the screen flickers. It seems a random stuff, but the one situation where it always happens is when I open Chrome and start typing in the address bar. The only way can get almost rid of the issue is by lowering the resolution by half, which makes things look really bad and still get the flickering from time to time.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** What kind of flickering? Like a too low refresh rate or screen tearing?

Comment: Try toggling GPU accelerated rendering in the browser settings?

Answer (score 0):

I have a lenovo thinkpad e550 with Intel HD Graphics 5500 and ubuntu 14.04. When I connect the monitor through VGA the monitor and hve the power connected it starts flickering! If I unplug the power it doesn't flicker. If I put it back it flickers. It seems to be a ground problem - not sure. Try to use tlp http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html. I installed tlp and the problem almost solved. Now it runs on high resolution and it flickers every  15 or 30 minutes for just a second or sometimes it doesn't flicker at all! But it is unstable sometimes work sometimes not